# Writing MongoDB Collection data to a csv using Talend

Tags: json, mongodb, export-to-csv, talend

I am trying to export MongoDB collection data to a CSV or JSON format using Talend, but I am unable to do that, I tried logging rows using tLogRow from tMongoDBInput, but rows are not being displayed, has anyone tried the same, I have MongoDB 3.4, and Talend version I am using is 7.0 TOS for big data.

Comment: Have you selected the required fields in the Edit Schema option in the tMongoDBInput and tLogRow components?